# Date Pattern matching in SAS

Tags: sas, pattern-matching

There is a variable in a dataset open_date  (in the form datetime19.  i.e.  08NOV2019:01:05:01 etc)
I need to perfom a patter check on the open_date
To verify as how may obs had date in format other that than datetime19.
Simply i need to apply patter check in open_date..  The valid format is datetime19.

Comment: What is the type and format of the current variable? What have you already tried? Here are instructions  [ask]

Comment: The variable has the datetime19. formats  but we need to setup the process where we are applying  checks on a varible.. So need to verify of all the obs are in same datetime19. format.    I tried using dictionary.columns and  found the  format of variable.  But its not helping for each obs

Comment: A variable in a dataset can only have one format for all observations. A numeric variable (no matter what format is attached to it) will always have numbers.  Are you trying to check if the numbers are reasonable for a datetime value?  Are you trying to analyze a character variable?  Or are you trying to analyze what is in a text file?

Comment: Once you've applied the format it's too late to those checks. You'd have to first import the data as a character field and then check the structure, likely using regex. Or you can use INPUT() assume it's the format and capture if an error is returned.